# Shared Handler preprocessor directive in MFC Document templates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have an application written using MFC doc-View framework. I used the application wizard to create a template for MFC application with document, view, mainframe, etc.

In the document class of my application, I see a piece of code as follows

```
#ifdef SHARED_HANDLERS

// Lots of code

#endif
```

What does the SHARED_HANDLERS preprocessor directive stand for?

Currently, the entire block is disabled since nowhere in my code is SHARED_HANDLER #defined. I was thinking of removing the block entirely, but then I was wary of breaking some code in future that #defines SHARED_HANDLER and relies on the block enclosed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the link below, the SHARED_HANDLERS is turned on if the project type is ATL DLL:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c16689/Supporting-Windows-Search-with-MFC.htm

Comment: Would you then expect that SHARED_HANDLERS will remain undefined unless I choose to import some components from the ATL?